# How to concate two fields in [formControlName]

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Reactive Form in Angular 8, I have some requirement where i need to concat two feilds into single field to make it Unique

My Controller Code

```
  const formGroup = {};
  this.searchFields.forEach(formControl => {
    formGroup[formControl.fieldName+formControl.fieldId] = new FormControl('');        
  });
  this.dynamicForm = new FormGroup(formGroup);
});
```

HTML Code

```
             <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'number'">
              <div class="input-group col-2">
                <label [for]="input.fieldName" class="imageSearchlabel">
                  <strong>{{input.DisplayName | translate }}:</strong></label>
                <input [formControlName]="input.fieldName+input.fieldId" [type]="input.valueType" [name]="input.fieldName"
                  class="form-control" value=""
                   />                                      
             </div>
            </ng-template>
```

Concatenation is not working in [formControlName], any help ??

Comment: What is the expected output here? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have dynamic form where i need to concat two fields into single feild to make it unqiue, but the appraoch i am using might be worng to concate, please suggest how to concat two fields value into single field

Comment: Sorry. Nope, that doesn't help.

Comment: @ArpitAJ post the related HTML code!

Comment: <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'number'">
                  <div class="input-group col-2">
                    <label [for]="input.fieldName" class="imageSearchlabel">
                      <strong>{{input.DisplayName | translate }}:</strong></label>
                    <input [formControlName]="input.fieldName+input.fieldId" [type]="input.valueType" [name]="input.fieldName"
                      class="form-control" value=""
                       />                                      
                 </div>
                </ng-template>

Comment: @ArpitAJ where is that `input` comes from? Is it running in the loop?

Comment: I mean where is that `input` variable comes?

Comment: Sorry for annswer in a comment: If you want to create a new Form you can NOT make using `//WRONG formGroup[formControl.fieldName+formControl.fieldId] = new FormControl(''); `, you need use addControl , see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl: `formGroup.addControl(formControl.fieldName+formControl.fieldId,new FormControl())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your HTML Code, but I would do like this:

```
this.searchFields.forEach(formControl => {
    let formGroup: any = {};
    this.searchFields.forEach(x => {
      x.FC_Name = x.fieldName + x.fieldId; --  store it here
      formGroup[x.FC_Name] = new FormControl();
    })
    this.dynamicForm = new FormGroup(formGroup);
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicForm">
<div *ngFor="let field of searchFields">
    <input [formControlName]="field.FC_Name">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the [`Working demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators-6q2hjp):

Comment: the problem is how Arpit create the formGroup :)